# No images or JS on new Magento 2 installation

Tags: magento2, installation

I've just installed Magento 2 onto my production server under a development. subdomain. The install appeared to have been successful but I've noticed there are no images or working javascript in both the frontend and the backend.

After inspecting the source code, I found that files being called in such as `http://dev.website.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_GB/css/print.css` don't actually exist. Any thoughts? I tried solutions on several stacks but haven't had any luck.

[image: Magento 2]

[image: Magento 2]

Comment: have you tried this --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492838/installing-magento-2-does-not-deploy-the-pub-static-frontend-and-backend/30497630#30497630

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this Before that take **Backup**

Remove everything, except `.htaccess` file from `pub/static folder`

Open up `app/etc/di.xml` find the path `“Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink”` and replace to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

Note: Remove entire files and folder under `pub/static` except `.htaccess` file.

For More info ref this http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/

Comment: Also, make sure you enabled [Apache server rewrites](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-help-rewrite).

Comment: This has fixed the frontend of my website. Images and styling is now also appearing in the backend, however - none of the links work. I'm getting loads of errors for missing files in pub/static - most of which don't exist.

Comment: i can't get.....

Comment: Fixed! I had to change the permissions of all directories in pub/static, as they were incorrect.

Comment: This is an accepted answer recommending modifying a core file. This is wrong and no one should do this.

Comment: to switch the static content deploy strategy, you should actually switch the mode to developer (symlink) or production (copy) with the command bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer / production. And like already said, do not edit the core :<

Comment: use this php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: I have tried everything,, still facing the same error,, may i know any other possibilities of error?

Comment: @Magento2 what is the root cause of this issue?

Answer (score 17):

You can run below command from magento root folder.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

This will download the content perfectly in respective folders.

Comment: This should be accepted website

Answer (score 3):

If you are in default or development mode use -f to forcefully download static content. In development mode static content are downloaded automatically.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: when i try for this my localhost, i am getting RunTimeEXception Error..

Answer (score 2):

If you see that Magento is trying to load from a folder other than en_US, you can try to deploy static content in the appropriate folder as below

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_AU
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after installing magento 2.1.1 and followed the steps mentioned below

1. Add D:\xampp\php to your PATH Environment Variable. Then Close The Command Prompt And Restart Again. Its important because if you didn't restart you command prompt then changes will not reflect.

Follow this link for guidance on adding path variable: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

2. Navigate to your mangento root directory (Eg: D:/xampp/mangento/) through command prompt
3. Run the command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

This worked for me. Hope it helps others!