# I am recently install magento 2.0 but not good result

Tags: magento2

[image]

Recently I installed magento 2.0 but I don't know it's not working. I dont know what is the mistake I made.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like permissions issue to me. Did you follow this documentation to setup your Magento 2 install permissions ? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **Before that take Backup**

1. Remove everything, except `.htaccess` file from `pub/static` folder
2. Open up `app/etc/di.xml` find the path `“Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink”` and replace to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

**Note**: Remove entire files and folder under pub/static except `.htaccess` file.

For More info ref this http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/

Comment: After This solution all css and js file not found.

Comment: check updated images

Comment: Clear var / cache

Comment: clear var/cache but not work :(

Comment: It's a working solution Follow that link carefully

Comment: yes. its working. sorry my mistake. :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to run below command form root:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

For more details, check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96304/23943