# Css and Js not load Magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, javascript, css

**Problem:**

I am installing Magento 2 on live server. While the site displays product info and some of the product images, there are no styles and JavaScript functions don't work.

**Solution attempts/debugging:**

I have seen a number of articles on inaccessible css/js files and have tried what they suggested to no avail. I follow instructions from here: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/259. But still no luck.

i've tried suggestion from Sandeep Pandey in https://mage2.pro/t/topic/259, it manage to solve the problem at first, but then when i change logo of my website or add new product, the problem occur again, the css and js wont load.

**Questions**

Does anyone have any ideas for solving this problem? Should i run command chmod 777 var -R & chmod 777 pub -R everytime i made changes on my website? Any suggestion?

Comment: try this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96289/no-images-or-js-on-new-magento-2-installation/96291#96291

Comment: In magento2 the permission are very closely maintained you can try out the steps mentioned in http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html#mage-owner-about-group and see if it helps

Comment: Solve it! Update into 2.0.6 and those problems gone. Thanks for the advice tho

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods to solve it:

- **Using command:**

  1. Open terminal and cd to magento installation directory.
  2. Run below command:

  `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
- **Manual:**

  1. Go to **`pub/static`** folder and remove everything, except .htaccess file.
  2. Open up app/etc/di.xml find the path **`Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink`** and replace to **`Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`**.
  3. Remove cache and reload frontend.

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

remove `var/view_preprocessed` folder

Answer (score -1):

Update to the latest version solve this problem.

Comment: This does not provide any explanation, but it's true, because in Magento 2.0.6 they made the file permissions less restrictive by default to address exactly this problem.