# Why is my dashboard like this?

Tags: magento2, admin, css

I set up a local host to install Magento, but ... after I installed Magento, I logged on to the dashboard. I don't know for certain what the problem is but I'm having problems with some objects which are not loading. I tried to re-install the Magento, but it didn't work?

Also the dropdown menu isn't working.

[image]

Comment: Try to run static content deploy?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run below command from Magento root as explained [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96304/23943)

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

try to run:

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area adminhtml