# Admin Panel of Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.0, admin-panel

I deleted `pub/static` folder of Magento 2 Admin Panel. Now my Magento 2 Admin Panel looks like below.

[image]

I ran below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

But it still remains as like before. How can I get the actual look ?

Comment: Try my answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96289/no-images-or-js-on-new-magento-2-installation/96291#96291

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download `.htaccess` from [official Magento 2 repository](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/pub/static)

Run below command.

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Keep in mind never delete `.htaccess` file from `pub/static`

Answer (score 1):

don't delete whole pub/static because inside static folder contain .htacess file. Please copy that file again and check it.