# No CSS and backed files after installation

Tags: magento2, css, installation

The installation went fine, no errors. I activated also rewriting mode for Apache2. But I found no CSS files:

The inspector shows:

[image]

The folder **`/pub/static`** has no version folder.

**UPDATE:**
Also I have no backend when I go to `localhost/admin`.

I didn't delete pub/static after my installation.
When I run `sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
I get error :

> [BadMethodCallException]
>   Missing required argument $alternativeSources of
>   Magento\Deploy\Model\Deploy\LocaleDeploy.

Comment: Run command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Check my answer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174296/admin-panel-of-magento-2/174303#174303

Comment: Didn't work, please see my update

Comment: Based on my knowledge, it is not an issue, please goto system > configuration > general > web > change the secure and unsecure urls from https to http

Comment: You have posted question under wrong tag. It should not be Magento-1.

Comment: Yes, sorry was a mistake, Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

First check if your css is loaded, your website -> right click and select view page source or just press ctrl+u. There you'll find your `style.css`. Check if it is showing this `style.css` and the right url. Click on it, see if it is loading ok.

It should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.exemple.com/skin/frontend/package/theme/css/style.css" media="all" />
```

For this problem to happen, There are three reasons I know of:

1.) There might be an issue because of System Cache. Clean the cache from the backend or go to `magentoroot/var/` and delete the contents of the cache and session folder.

2.) There can be issue with the file permission of your css File. In this case just type the following command in terminal, `sudo chmod 777 -R /magentoroot/` (**update file permissions after Magento creates these new static files. They are not owned by www-data, so they will give 404.**)

3.) Lastly, there could be something wrong with the url in your core_config_data table of your database, which I think you have already checked.

4.) Flush your navigator cache : `Ctrl+Shift+R`

Comment: The CSS file itself doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

Run following steps and commands from terminal of your magento installation root directory.

> Step 1 : Deploy the static content to create symlinks

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

> Step 2 : Reindex files

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

> Step 3: Enable rewrite module extension

```
make sure apache “rewrite_module” is enable and then restart the server
```

> Step 4 : Give you WebServer access

```
$ chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2
```

> Step 5:  Give write permission.

```
$ chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2
```

> Step 6: Clean and flush magento cache

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this helps you !!

Comment: I get   [BadMethodCallException]                                                                    
  Missing required argument $alternativeSources of Magento\Deploy\Model\Deploy\LocaleDeploy.  
when I run your first command