# Getting blank screen while trying to install Magento version 2.1.7 from Localhost in ubuntu

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, installation, magento-2.1.7

i am trying to install `Magento version 2.1.7`. I have installed appache2, mysql and php, all are running well. I used `composer install` to install all the dependencies required. After that i went to browser and directed through the `localhost/magento2/` directory to get the setup running.

But i get a blank screen !
can anyone suggest me what else can be done ?

Comment: Did you set FIle Permission

Comment: Hi ! @Kothari thanks for your advice, I actually was able to install it properly.

Comment: Hi ! @Kothari thanks for your advice, I actually was able to install it properly. I gave file permissions as well and the installation went good. But now i am having a problem again as  after the installation when i go to  `localhost/magento2/` i get a `blank screen` again and  a page of `Not Found` error `The requested URL /magento21/admin was not found on this server.` when i try to go to admin.

Comment: After the complete installation when i went to `localhost/megento2` i saw the home page but all the `CSS` was not working. So i went to clear the cache and setup upgrade and from `app/etc/di.xml`  i re-copied this line `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy` form `<item name="default"` to its above `<item name=""view_preprocessed`. Any how this procedure would have definitely worked in a windows PC. But i am using Ubuntu. Can you please suggests what can be done.

Comment: Try this php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy remove pub/static except .htaccess then run that cmd

Comment: Try my answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96289/no-images-or-js-on-new-magento-2-installation/96291#96291

Comment: Hi @Kothari ! i did the `setup:static-content:deploy` command and removed the file's except the `.htacess` from `pub/static/`... but still i get the same results.

Comment: Still blank page

Comment: yes ! its still blank