# Magento 2 Theme Css Not Loading

Tags: error, theme, css, magento-2.1.7

How can i solve this error?

[image]

Note : I did **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

May I know what is the issue?

There is no error in logs.

Comment: Hi Check my answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96289/no-images-or-js-on-new-magento-2-installation/96291#96291

Comment: I hope this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly two will be the reason

**case-1 :-**  There will be no .htaccess file in pub/static 
if not then please copy a htaccees files from fresh magento2 path pub/static
 and place in your pub folder.

**case - 2** In your system symlink is not enabled so please enable it.