# why my admin dashboard looks like this

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.1

i already run commands 
setup:upgrade
static-content:deploy
indexer
di:compile
cache:flush
why my admin dashboard looks like this ? 
[image]

Comment: which OS are you using ?

Comment: it is live server. ubuntu maybe .

Comment: Check this first https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96289/no-images-or-js-on-new-magento-2-installation

Comment: Have you checked in your console? Please make sure it's not language issue.
If you found any error in console please add this error in question 
may be i can help you.. @samairali

Answer (score 0):

Run your code like this and it'll most likely correct it:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US  && chmod -R 777 var pub/static  && php bin/magento indexer:reindex &&  php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I use this all the time, it seems to be best order, and it fully refreshes all generated content. Please bear in mind, depending on the number of products/categories/customers/orders etc. it may take a little while.

EDIT: Also please note, this has the static content for en_GB and en_US languages, but obviously just select what you require, I do both as it clears up some issues that admins sometimes have with languages/translations and admin user accounts.